# SetProgress not working in ListViewItem with ProgressBar without notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a list view and items have an image button and a ProgressBar.

I what the ProgressBar to be updated(Progress set) from a Thread.

Whenever getView in list adapter be invoked list view items will be instantiated 
and the reference to the ProgressBar will change.so i put the last reference of ProgressBar in a HashMap in the adapter and when i want to update ProgressBar i use it as the last reference.

But it works differently depending on number of items.when the size of items is too much and list view is in scroll mode it works properly but with one or two items that fit in one page without scrolling, ProgressBar will get stuck but with selecting one item, ProgressBar continues with no problem.

It seems after last getView and next notifyDataSetChanged() that may be caused by list selection or Scrolling, ProgressBar's reference had been changed out of getView() so i can not have the last one(or no,i don't know!).

I also tried notifyDataSetChanged() on every setProgress but it is not efficient and also blocks imageButton OnClickListener.

here is adapter code:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Message> messagesItems;

private Map<Message,ProgressWheel> ProgressBars =new HashMap<>();//to have last reference to the ProgressBar corresponding to each listItem
public  Map<Message,Boolean>  showProgress=new HashMap<>();//for some controlling
public  Map<Message,Boolean>  active=new HashMap<>();//for some controlling
public  Map<Message,View>  layouts=new HashMap<>();//for some controlling
public  Map<Message,View>  views=new HashMap<>();//for some controlling
final static android.os.Handler mHandler=new android.os.Handler();

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Message currentMessage = (Message) getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView==null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_right, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
         }else {
            viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        ImageButton sendButton= viewHolder.SkipButton;
        View progressLayout= convertView.findViewById(R.id.proressLayout);
        //ProgressWheel is a custom progressBar
        ProgressWheel progressWheel = viewHolder.progressBar;

        ProgressBars.put(currentMessage, progressWheel);
        layouts.put(currentMessage,progressLayout);
        views.put(currentMessage, convertView);

        if(showProgress.get(currentMessage)!=null) {
            if (showProgress.get(currentMessage)) {
                progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                sendButton.setTag(currentMessage);

  //ProgressBarHandler.start just runs a thread and increments progress in   background by calling setDelayProgress from this class

                if (active.get(currentMessage) == null) {
                    active.put(currentMessage, true);

                    ProgressBarHandler progressBarHandler = new ProgressBarHandler(currentMessage, this,this);
                    progressBarHandler.start(10);

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (active.get(currentMessage) == false) {
                    active.put(currentMessage, true);

                    ProgressBarHandler progressBarHandler = new ProgressBarHandler(currentMessage, this,this);
                    progressBarHandler.start(10);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            } else {
                progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }else
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
 public void setDelayProgress(final Message message, final int progress, final   long durationMillis){
   mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           ProgressBars.get(message).setProgress(progress);

             //  notifyDataSetChanged();// is cause the code extremely inefficient But working !
       }
   });


}

final static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView message;
    public ProgressWheel progressBar;
    public ImageButton SkeepButton;



    public ViewHolder(View convertView){
        this.message = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
        this.progressBar = (ProgressWheel) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.delayProgress);
        this.SkeepButton = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sendb);

    }
}

}
```

Your suggestions would be appreciated,Thanks

Comment: Maybe you will provide some code? Adapter, progress and so on.

Comment: For first look - its very strange solution. In this case I will prefere AsyncTask and his methods publishProgress and onProgressUpdate.

Comment: there is no problem with thread or Async Task because setDelayProgress() is calling continuously but ProgressBar is not Updating

Comment: Well, now you need to debug this. I think nobody doing this for yourself. Or you may try to change this system on more simple with AsyncTask. For me its very strange and hard solution.

Comment: thank but i want to know is it possible for progressbar's reference to be changed out of get view for example by garbage collector?

Comment: it would be great if some one show me a good and simple way to handle ProgressBars in listview.